# What citation styles are currently supported by ConTeXt?

Tags: bibtex, citing, context

I'm not sure where to find the latest details, as the manuals and Wiki sometimes contains heavily outdated information.

What are the currently supported citation styles that can be used in ConTeXt? Are there others that can be added via external modules?

[This ConTeXt Garden link](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuppublications) lists `ams apa apa-de apa-fr aps num num-fr ssa`, but are those all really supported? I can't even get `\setuppublications` to work, I think `\usebtxdefinitions` is the way I'm setting the style, and some like "num" don't seem to work.

Comment: The distribution provides `apa`, `aps`, and `chicago` but there are also some third-party ones that have to be installed manually, e.g. https://gist.github.com/adityam/afda949f76676055e7906679599ec937